# google maps - define active action area for bounds and InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way in [`Google Maps JavaScript API V3`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) to define an area within all the `bounds` and `listener` are working?

*I'm not sure how to describe what I'm looking for*. But I created an example (s. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/1n1L60fv/)) to make it more clear:

[image: example infowindow]

For example there is an [`InfoWindow`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindowOptions) which should only popup within the as active marked area above the search input.

Further the bound of search results should be shown above the search filed as well like that:

[image: google map bound areas]

Is there a way to manipulate the [`Google Maps JavaScript API V3`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) in the way I tried to described?

---

**EDIT:** Added the solution ideas as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45665440/3001970) *(they were previously explained here in the question section)*...

Comment: What is wrong about my question? Pls explain before -1 vote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I probably (*thx to the negative voting*) won't get any help here I will post my solution for the moment. *Hope that helps somebody in the future.*

From what I can see, there is no standard solution for that problem, so I divided the problem into two part:

1. The corrected displaying of the [`InfoWindow`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=de#InfoWindow). The only option I found is to overwrite the `max-height`. That works for now as long the marker is above the search input:

   ***JS:***

   ```js
   google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
       var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
       iwOuter.children(':nth-child(1)').addClass('custom-iw');
   });
   ```

   ***CSS:***

   ```css
   .custom-iw {
       max-height: calc(100vh - 120px - 160px) !important;
       /**
        * 100vh total map height
        * 120px the position of the search input
        * 160px the size of the marker and the margin above the InfoWindow
        **/
   }
   ```

   See the [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/1n1L60fv/1/) and click the marker to see what I meant.

   [image: screenshot jsfiddle]

---

2. For the search result of the input filed. I corrected the bound by subtracted a relative part of the height of the bound itself. Therewith the result is show a little above the search input.

   **JS**

   ```js
   var ne = bounds.getNorthEast(); 
   var sw = bounds.getSouthWest(); 
   var heightInput = Math.abs(parseInt($('.map-search').css('margin-top'))); 
   var factor = $('#map').height() / heightInput;
   var south = sw.lat() - (ne.lat() - sw.lat())/factor;  // That's where happens the correction      
   bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
       new google.maps.LatLng(south, sw.lng()),
       new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), ne.lng())            
   );
   ```

   See the [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/1n1L60fv/2/) and input a search query (eg. *Easter Island*) to see what I meant.

   [image: screenshot jsfiddle 2]